# Query on Javascript RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that allows 0-9, a-z, A-Z, hyphen, question mark and "/" slash characters alone. Also the length should be between 5 to 15 only.

I tried as follows, but it does not work:

```
var reg3 = /^([a-zA-Z0-9?-]){4,15}+$/;
alert(reg3.test("abcd-"));
```

Comment: you need to change the 4 to a 5 at least

Comment: If you want between 5 and 15, why did you write `{4,15}`?  Also, what is `{4,15}+` supposed to mean?  The `+` means `{0,}`, it's not needed.

Comment: Try some online regex editor, it will help you learn quicker because you can play with the regex. [refiddle](http://refiddle.com/) is an example.

Answer (score 4):

> length should be between 5 to 15 only

Is that why you have this?

```
{4,15}+
```

Just use `{5,15}`; it’s already a quantifier, and a `+` after it won’t work. Apart from that, the group isn’t necessary, but things should work.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9?/-]{5,15}$/
```

(I also added a slash character.)

Answer (score 0):

Couple issues,

1. you need `{5,15}` instead of `{4,15}+`
2. need to include `/`

Your code can be rewritten as

```
var reg3 = new RegExp('^[a-z0-9?/-]{5,15}$', 'i'); // i flag to eliminate need of A-Z
alert(reg3.test("a1?-A7="));
```

**Update**

Let's not confuse *can* be with *MUST* be and concentrate on the actual thing I was trying to convey.

`{4,15}+` part in `/^([a-zA-Z0-9?-]){4,15}+$/` should be written as `{5,15}`, and `/` must be included; which will make your regexp

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9?/-]){5,15}$/
```

which **CAN** be written as

```
/^[a-z0-9?/-]{5,15}$/i   // i flag to eliminate need of A-Z
```

Also I hope everybody is OK with use of `/i`

Comment: You know you can do `var reg3 = /^([a-z0-9?\-]){5,15}$/i;`, right?  You don't need to use `new RegExp`.

Comment: Yes that's true (and I know).

Comment: Can be rewritten? Sure, but it’s not better. `new RegExp` is inappropriate on static strings.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
if (/^([a-z\/?-]{4,15})$/i.test(subject)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

***REGEX EXPLANATION***

```
^([a-z\/?-]{4,15})$

Options: Case insensitive

Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([a-z\/?-]{4,15})»
   Match a single character present in the list below «[a-z\/?-]{4,15}»
      Between 4 and 15 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{4,15}»
      A character in the range between “a” and “z” (case insensitive) «a-z»
      The literal character “/” «\/»
      The literal character “?” «?»
      The literal character “-” «-»
Assert position at the very end of the string «$»
```